# How to select just previous row of the last row

Tags: jquery

How to select just previous row of the last row?

My html code:

```
<table id="table1">
 <tr><td>test</td></tr>
 <tr><td>test</td></tr>
 <tr><td>test</td></tr>
 <tr><td><select></select></td></tr>
 <tr><td>test</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to give option to the  using jquery.

js:

```
$('#table1 tr:last select').prev().append("<option>rose</option>");
```

But it doesn't worked.
Please help.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xzj5m3w8/

Comment: thankzz. It works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tr:last select` will look for select in last row. you need to find the last row first, traverse to previous tr and then find select element in it. Like this:

```
$('#table1 tr:last').prev().find('select').append("<option>rose</option>");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/byy40eaa/)**

From the markup it appears that you have only single select. if that is the case always, you need not have to do all the traversing and stuff. `$('#table1 select')` will work for targeting single select element.

Answer (score 2):

In the specific table there is only one `select` element, so you can just use `find()` in the parent table:

```
$('#table1').find('select').append('<option>rose</option>');
```

Another approach would be this:

```
$('#table1 tr').each(function() {
   var that = $(this);
   var l = that.find('select').length;
   if (l > 0) {
      // the row has a select element ...
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('#table1 tr:nth-last-child(2)').find('select').append("<option>rose</option>");
```